# What's a good way to default behavior if a plugin is inactive?

Tags: plugins, theme-options

I'm currently building a framework that enhances a few things such as:

1. Custom Customizer Controls
2. Custom Single Post Layouts
3. etc.

For example, this means that on my `single.php` I call `framework\GetCustomPostLayout()`, the problem with that is my framework is a plugin which needs to be installed, so errors will show if it's not enabled.

I'm looking for a way to do

```
if( function_exists( 'Framework' ) ) { 
    get_framework_behavior
} else {
    get_nonframework_behavior_default 
}
```

Unfortunately, even this is transformed into a wrapper such as:

`getCustomPostLayout` that checks within itself that the plugin is activated, I'd have to write my default behavior inside of it, making me put logic that's supposed to be in `single.php` in another file.

How could I best approach this?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the WordPress `is_plugin_active()` function? - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active

This is an admin only function though, so to use it in the frontend or within a template file you would need to manually require plugin.php like so:

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
is_plugin_active($plugin);
```

Where `$plugin` is the name of the plugin sub directory/file eg:

`is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/plugin-file.php' );`

Comment: That did come up, yes, but that was the issue - only back-end. I'll wait for another answer, I'm not too sure `function_exists` is as clean and perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: The above function can be used in the frontend by requiring the `plugin.php` file first, as per my example. I've also seen `class_exists` used to check if WooCommerce is active/installed before... If `function_exists` works for you then I think this would be fine and cleaner than using the `is_plugin_active` function... Don't think you're going to find any 'cleaner' way of checking...

Comment: I'd also be inclined to question, that if the functionality is specific to your theme, then why are you adding the functionality with a plugin instead of coding the functionality directly in to your themes code? Or is your plugin intended to be used on multiple sites and then site owners/theme authors would need to add conditional code to their template files to utilise the functionality of your plugin?